# Bookmarklet to actually click on checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, bookmarklet

I have a page where on one side I have several different objects and on the other a checkbox grid, the same for everyone, but values are customized for each object. 
Obj A can have box 1 selected and 2 unselected, 
Obj B can have box 1 unselected and 2 selected 
but the Grid scheme itself is the same for all the objects.
I need to be able to copy the checkboxes values from one specific object onto another object and save my work on server side.
I created a pure JS bookmarklet that saves into the sessionStorage the actual values of 'checked' of a Checkbox Grid:

```
javascript: var test = []; 
   var check = document.getElementsByClassName("CheckboxGrid");  
   for (var i = 0; i < check.length; i++)   {    
                      test.push(check[i].checked);}  
   sessionStorage.setItem('val', JSON.stringify(test));
```

And a second bookmarklet that I use on the same page to copy the values of the Checkbox Grid:

```
javascript: var gridValues = sessionStorage.getItem('val'); //returns an array of Char
   var i = 0; 
   var y = 0; 
   var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("CheckboxGrid");

   while (y<checkboxes.length) 
   {     
        if (gridValues[i] == 't')
                     {checkboxes[y].checked=true; y++; i++;}
        else if (gridValues[i] == 'f')
                     {checkboxes[y].checked=false; y++; i++;}
        else     {i++;}
   }
```

The code 'works', meaning that on the screen I see the exact copy of the first Grid on the second one; the problem is that it looks like the 2nd bookmarklet is just changing the 'look' of the boxes, and not actually manipulating them.
In fact, when I save or click on a checkbox everything goes back as it was before bookmarklets actions.

Am I doing something wrong? Is it actually possible to have a bookmarklet click on a checkbox and keep its changes on the page even after later user-input (e.g. clicking on another box)?

Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

First of all let's make your second script more readable:

```
javascript: var gridValues = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('val'));
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("CheckboxGrid");
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++)   {    
    checkboxes[i].checked = gridValues[i];
}
```

The code itself should work fine. It is setting checkboxes to a correct state, not just visually.

What do you mean saying "when I save"? There's any logic for saving selection to the server? Is there any other JS that could potentially manipulate your checkboxes?

Comment: When I use this page and manually tick/untick checkboxes on a specific object, I have to click on a save button to keep the changes, otherwise they will be automatically discarded. As per my understanding it's the only time when the server Is contacted - I'm a noob and might be missing something though :)

Comment: The fact is I think the bookmarklet itself is not really 'writing' on the grid rather than just changing the grid look instead. When I manually work on the page and tick/untick a box, I can see a red dot close to the amended checkbox to quickly see what I changed; when I run the 2nd script instead this red dot does not show up

Comment: There could be anything :) If the issue is in that you're sending to server one set of checkboxes, but after reload server returns you a different one, there's a chance that in fact your page detects selected checkboxes in a different way. It might not be checking "checked" of a real checkbox. If there's any way to verify. what is sent to the server - need to check this first (e.g. in Network tab if it is XHR, or enable "Preserve log" if saving works with page reload)